# How to store 0.0001352?

Tags: java, format, double, decimal

I have a class that has a double 'sizeinMegs' variable and whenever the value is tiny, say 0.00025 megs, it simply stores 0.0 as seen in the debug watch.

How do I save it in all its decimal glory?

Here's my code:

```
        thePdf.setFileSizeInMegaBytes((theFile.length() / 1000000)); //that's a double

        double size = theFile.length(); // this returns say 12345
        size = size / 1000000; this returns 0.012345
        double storedValue = thePdf.getFileSizeInMegaBytes(); // this shows 0.0 in the watch window

        String value;
        value = fmt(size); //this shows the right value in the string

        lblTest.setText("Size: " +  value + " MB"); 

 ....

public static String fmt(double d)
{
    if(d == (int) d)
        return String.format("%d",(int)d);
    else
        return String.format("%s",d);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of double, that way you won't lose precision.
Can you show code in:

```
thePdf.setFileSizeInMegaBytes()
```

and

```
thePdf.getFileSizeInMegaBytes()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping :) Here's how they are set:  public double getFileSizeInBytes() { return m_db_FileSizeInBytes; }
 public void setFileSizeInBytes(double value) { m_db_FileSizeInBytes = value; }

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell here, because i can't see the declaration of "theFile", but if the length() method is returning a long or int value, then the very first line of your program is doing integer/long division, and thus any value < 1 becomes 0.

If that's the case here, cast the length to a double first.

THe reason the second part works is that this declaration has an implicit cast from int/long to double, and thus any subsequent calculations results in doubles.

double size = theFile.length();

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is integer division.  Instead of

```
theFile.length() / 1000000
```

which will always round downwards, you could write

```
theFile.length() / 1000000.0
```

which forces this to be a non-integer division.

Whenever you place `/` between two expressions of `int` type, the result will be an `int` too, and it will be rounded.